# Convert Local File URL to File Path

Tags: python, url, local, filepath

I have a URL that points to a local file.

```
'file:///home/pi/Desktop/music/Radio%20Song.mp3'
```

I need to somehow convert this into a traditional file path, like the `os` module employs.

```
'/home/pi/Desktop/music/Radio Song.mp3'
```

Right now I'm hacking it with the `replace()` method.

```
path = file.replace('file://', '').replace('%20', ' ')
```

I've looked at the `os` module, and it doesn't seem to have support for this. I've searched various ways of phrasing it, and I can't seem to find an answer. Am I just ignorant of the terminology? What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Use the `urllib` module to parse URLs.

Comment: You need to remove `file://`, not just `file:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following would work:

```
from urllib.request import url2pathname
from urllib.parse import urlparse

p = urlparse('file:///home/pi/Desktop/music/Radio%20Song.mp3')
file_path = url2pathname(p.path)
print(file_path)
```

(thanks to user @MillerTime correctly pointing out that the solution will not remove `file://`  without the `urlparse`)

Output:

```
/home/pi/Desktop/music/Radio Song.mp3
```

`urllib` is a standard library, so no installation required.

On a Windows machine, running just `url2pathname` would give you a valid file path right away, but it would be relative to the working directory of the script - e.g. running it from somewhere on D: drive:

```
D:\home\pi\Desktop\music\Radio Song.mp3
```